# 2 scripts (FitVids.js, Vimeo.js) together kill Calling a function to play video, resulting in: VimeoAPI is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, vimeo

**Update** below...

Ok, ive got a problem here. Im using this excellent vimeo class to make my life easier:
http://www.josh-ho.com/vimeo-class/
(source code here: http://labs.josh-ho.com/vimeo/Vimeo.js)

i use it together with the fitvids.js, which is sooo great, found here:
http://fitvidsjs.com/
(source code here: https://raw.github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/master/jquery.fitvids.js)n

problem is, in firefox (OSX, havent tried WIN yet, but probably will, too) it breaks the vimeoAPI as soon i use fitvids.js, so i cant get events or tell Vimeo.js to play the video, nor stop it. Works as expected (and wanted) in Safari, though...

i know it must have sth to do with the fact that the fitvids.js puts my div (in which my object swf player is in) in another div:

Before:

```
<div id="flashposition">
<object width="1280" height="720" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
id="flashpositionmyFlashID" data="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf"><param 
name="swliveconnect" value="true"><param name="fullscreen" value="1"><param 
name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="clip_id=35083232&
amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=false&amp;show_byline=false&amp;show_portrait=0&
amp;fullscreen=true&amp;js_api=1&amp;js_onLoad=vimeo.vimeoLoaded&amp;color=00adef&
amp;wmode=transparent"></object>
</div>
```

After:

```
<div id="flashposition">

**<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">**

<object width="1280" height="720" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
id="flashpositionmyFlashID" data="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf"><param 
name="swliveconnect" value="true"><param name="fullscreen" value="1"><param 
name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="clip_id=35083232&
amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=false&amp;show_byline=false&amp;show_portrait=0&
amp;fullscreen=true&amp;js_api=1&amp;js_onLoad=vimeo.vimeoLoaded&amp;color=00adef&
amp;wmode=transparent"></object>
</div>

**</div>**
```

in Vimeo.js is a function

```
XXX.play.video();
```

which calls

```
vimeoAPI.api_play();
```

And *vimeoAPI* is defined as:

```
vimeoAPI = document.getElementById( vimeoContainer ).getElementsByTagName( "object" )[0];
```

*vimeocontainer* id say is in my example the div id "flashposition".

So my guess is that it cant access the api because there is this new div with class="fluid-width-video-wrapper".

So how do i have to change vimeoAPI to get it working again (if this is the culprit)?

Many, many thanks in advance!

**Update**

The code works now in Firefox, but only if I leave the page to a different URL (by staying in the same browser window) and then pressing the back button. then everything *is* working and the vimeo API up and running.
But how do I fix this now?

Heres the updated code that got me that far:

fitvids expects pure width and height, not with px added. So I stripped that from the Vimeo.js code in line 137-138, resulting in:

```
playerWidth = ( width.toString().search( 'px' ) != -1 || width.toString().search( '%' )     
!= -1 ) ? width.toString() : width;

playerHeight = ( height.toString().search( 'px' ) != -1 || height.toString().search( '%' 
) != -1 ) ? height.toString() : height;
```

Then I changed lines in

```
this.vimeoLoaded = function() {
var NEWcontainer = vimeoContainer + "NEW";
$('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').attr('id', NEWcontainer);
$(document.getElementById( vimeoContainer ).getElementsByTagName( "object" )).attr('id', 
NEWcontainer);
container = NEWcontainer;
vimeoAPI = document.getElementById( vimeoContainer ).getElementsByTagName( "object" )
[0];
setupAddEventListener();
jQuery(document.getElementById( vimeoContainer )).fitVids();
dispatchEvent( this.VIMEO_LOAD_COMPLETE, null );
}
```

and finally called Vimeo.js class as normal:

```
var vimeo;
vimeo = new Vimeo( "flashposition", 1280, 720, "vimeo", showTitle=false);
vimeo.loadVideo( '35083232' );

vimeo.addEventListener( vimeo.VIMEO_LOAD_COMPLETE, video1Loading );

function video1Loading() {
vimeo.playVideo();
}
```

This way it "works", but again, only when pressing the back button... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize fitvid before vimeo (since it changes the DOM) and initialize vimeo on the new inner div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div = $("#flashposition");
    $div.fitVids();

    // grab the new div and give it an id (for vimeo to find)
    var vimeoID = 'vimeoPlayer';
    $div.children('div.fluid-width-video-wrapper').attr('id', vimeoID);

    // vimeo is not a jquery plugin and searches DOM by id
    var vimeo = new Vimeo(vimeoID, 480, 320, “vimeo”);

    //....

    vimeo.playVideo();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didnt work so well :-(
Now I have a blank screen and:
Vimeo not defined...

Comment: ok, thank you! Getting closer, but still not working right. i inserted your code and changed it to my setup, that is:
var vimeoID = 'flashposition';
and:
var vimeo = new Vimeo( vimeoID, 1280, 720, "vimeo", showTitle=false);
But it still doesnt work :-( FitVids isnt executed, nor does it play because of that.
console barks vimeo, div not defined...
Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: `var vimeoID = "flashposition"` is wrong because it refers to the outter div.  You need to initialize Vimeo on the inner div, but Vimeo can only find elements by "id" attribute.  The inner div has no "id", you must add an arbitrary "id" (eg, "vimeoPlayer") and then pass that "id" to the Vimeo constructor.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! ;-)
Got your point there! Thanks for clarifying that one.
But even when I change it back to "vimeoPlayer" (or whatever else, as it wont make a diff, given the following $div.children..., right?), Vimeo.js doesnt populate the "flashposition" div in the first place, so fitvids also has nothing to work with.
In console I get:
document.getElementByID(vimeoContainer) is null
(Vimeo.js, line 86)

Comment: Am i wrong that the problem might be, that before calling vimeo.loadVideo(), theres only an empty div with id "flashposition", so when I call fitvids *first* it has nothing to find to do its magic on? Sorry, if I´m sound confusing (actually I am ;-) ), or am I completely off track here?

Comment: Yes you are right about that, I misunderstood the function of fitvid.js.  DOM location is probably wrong, and order should not matter because it is purely CSS based.

Comment: ah, ok. So i have to do two things as a solution, I guess.
First, changing order of the script above, like that perhaps? -->
http://jsfiddle.net/GmExL/3/
And second, I would have to give the fitvid div the id of the Vimeo.js container variable, which, in my case is "flashposition".
Which would result in two divs with the same id, which wouldnt work, right?
So add to the "fluid" Div an ID like "NEW" + container (Vimeo.js variable, here "flashposition") and then change container variable to the new div fluid ID´s (NEWcontainer)?

Comment: Aargh, my head starts smoking. Seeing "a solution" to do something is one thing hard enough for me, but coding it another!
Would you help me out, please?

Comment: Actually, the code *does* work, when I leave the page to a different address in the same window and press then the back button - then everything works as expected...
Thats ...somehow even more frustrating!