# Code (ok in other browsers) working in Firefox only when clicking back button / on.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

So heres my problem:
The code only works, when I leave the page to a different url (in the same browser window) and then press the back button.

What could be the reason for such an odd behavior? Any hints where and what to look for?

I know its not a specific question but a general one, because i hope to get guidance so someone can hint me to the "desease" by me describing the symptons (Dr.House-style) so I get a good start for finding the bug.
So i hope this is ok to ask.

**Anyhow, if it needs to be specific, here is the code that is acting so strangely:**
[2 scripts (FitVids.js, Vimeo.js) together kill Calling a function to play video, resulting in: VimeoAPI is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980378/)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that means that VimeoAPI is not a function. :) You may be spelling it wrong, capitalizing it wrong, or it may not be defined yet. Try posting your code clearly on your post.

Comment: I made an update on the (other) post with detailed code. Hope that helps. But the problem is, that (in Firefox without the back button "trick") Firefox tries to execute the pages network requests twice when looking at firebugs network tab...